# Can't call method 'isBinary' on an undefined value

Tags: perl, mime

I am trying to make a tinier, more optimized CGI module for Perl.

When working on the `init` subroutine to get, or set default file data, I run into an issue primarily caused with the `MIME::Types` module.

In reality, my init subroutine is supposed to get the blessed variables from the `new` constructor, initialize `MIME::Types`, use `MIME::Types` to return the MIME::Type of $type via `mimeTypeOf()`, determine if the MIME::Type is binary, and print out the Content-Type and Content-Disposition.

However, when trying to do something of that nature, I get the title as the error.

This is my current code, which in theory should work.

```perl
sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_; 
    my $self = {};
    my $type = $args{type} // 'text/html'; # If type isn't defined, default to HTML content.
    my $attachment = ($args{attachment} // 'false') eq 'true' ? 'attachment' : 'inline'; # Same, but with disposition instead.
    $self->{type} = $type;
    $self->{attachment} = $attachment;
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    CORE::state $type = shift // $self->{type}; # If there are no overrides, just use $self->type;
    # print $self->type; prints text/html when not specified.
    CORE::state $attachment = shift // $self->{attachment}; # Same as above, but with $self->attachment;
    # print $self->attachment; prints inline when not specified.
    my $types = MIME::Types->new;
    my $mime = $types->mimeTypeOf($type);
    if ($mime->isBinary) {
        $self->{attachment} = 'attachment';
    } else {
        $self->{attachment} = ('inline' or $attachment);
    }
    die "Warning: Binary content types should not be sent inline!\r\n" if ($mime->isBinary && $attachment eq 'inline');
    print "Content-Type: $mime\r\nContent-Disposition: $self->{attachment}\r\n\r\n";
    return;
}
```

Even printing the types return a non undefined value, in fact, it prints out what it's supposed to when there's nothing inside of the new method. This is the code which is in my main CGI file.

```perl
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;
use TinyCGI::Core;

# Create a new TinyCGI::Core object
my $cgi = TinyCGI::Core->new();

# Initialize the TinyCGI::Core object
$cgi->init();

print 'Hello, World!';
```

This worked perfectly fine without MIME::Types, and even works just fine with stuff actually defined within the object.

I've also tried not using `CORE::state`.

Comment: According to the [doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Types#$obj-%3EmimeTypeOf($filename)) `mimeTypeOf()` expects a filename as argument. You do not pass a filename so it returns undef. You can‘t call methods on undef.

Comment: Re "*when value actually is defined*", If Perl says it's an undefined value, and you say it's a defined value, who do you think I believe?

Comment: Well no shit, you're supposed to believe the interpreter, but if you read the previous comment it actually wasn't the variable that was the problem, it was the wrong function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `MIME::Types` incorrectly. It looks like you want to take the value from an HTTP header (or maybe multi-part body header) and figure out what it is. You are using `mimeTypeOf`, which expects a file extension or filename, when you should be using `type`, which expects a type string.

Either way, there's a chance that you could get back an undef value because `MIME::Types` might not be able to map the string to a type. You should guard against that:

```
my $type = $mime->type( $self->{type} );
if( defined $type ) { ... }
```

---

Unrelated to that, you are using `CORE::state` for some reason. That makes it look like you are defining some method or subroutine named `state` and expecting it to conflict with the Perl built-in.

But I don't think you want `state` here. You have an instance method `init` that is for some reason persisting a value based on an earlier created, unrelated instance. I think you want `my`, since you are merely giving a local name to something that's already inside the invoking instance. You don't want to persist that to the next instance that calls this.